# Is there any other function other than $f(x)=x$ satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)|= |x-y|$ where $f : [0,1]\to [0,1]$

Tags: functions

Let $f : [0,1]\to [0,1]$  satisfy $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|$$ for all $x,y\in [0,1]$

$f(x)=x$ satisfies this. Is there any other function that does?

Comment: What does "modulus" mean in this situation?

Comment: My guess is that it is the absolute value.

Comment: Most likely the absolute value

Comment: yes. absolute value of f(x)- f(y)= absolute value of x-y

Answer (score 5):

For $x=0$ and $y=1$ we get
$$
 |f(1) - f(0)| = |1-0| = 1 \implies f(1) - f(0) = \pm 1 
$$
so that

- either $f(0)=0$ and $f(1) = 1$,
- or $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$.

In the first case it follows that for all $x \in [0, 1]$
$$
 f(x) = |f(x)| = |f(x) - f(0)| = |x-0| = x \,
$$
and in the second case
$$
 1 - f(x) = |1-f(x)| = |f(0) - f(x)| = |0-x| = x \,
$$
so that $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = 1-x$ are the only solutions.

Comment: Nice and easy! +1

Answer (score 3):

Yes: take the map $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow[0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=1-x$.

Comment: I think this is the only other function

Comment: Yes, the identity and this one are the only ones.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that on a graph, for a line $f$ with the two points $(x,f(x))$ and $(y, f(y))$, the horizontal displacement is $|y-x|$ and the vertical is $|f(y)-f(x)|$. You require that these be equal, in other words

$$y=x+t \implies f(y)=f(x)+t \tag1$$ and so $f$ is expressible in vector notation:

$$\binom{y}{f(y)}=\binom{x}{f(x)}+\lambda\binom tt$$
and thusly must be a straight line.

Now just rule out the straight lines it can't be, using $(1)$